# Rust mut borrow fail in closure

Tags: rust

Here is my code

```
struct test_loop {
    is_break: bool,
}
impl test_loop {
    fn run_forever<F>(&mut self, mut f: F)
    where
        F: FnMut() -> (),
    {
        self.is_break = false;
        loop {
            f();
            if self.is_break {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    fn breakit(&mut self) {
        self.is_break = true;
    }
}
fn main() {
    let mut l = test_loop { is_break: false };
    let f = || {
        l.breakit();
    };
    l.run_forever(f);
}
```

The code is simple, and I don't want to skip calling `l.breakit()` in the closure. Now the compiler tells me there is a second mutable borrow problem:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `l` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:26:5
   |
23 |     let f = || {
   |             -- first mutable borrow occurs here
24 |         l.breakit();
   |         - first borrow occurs due to use of `l` in closure
25 |     };
26 |     l.run_forever(f);
   |     ^             - first borrow later used here
   |     |
   |     second mutable borrow occurs here
```

I used a `RefCell` to fix the compilation problem, but the thread still panics during run-time. Should I remove the `l.xxx` in the closure? Or there's some way to make the code act like it is running in C++ or another language?

Comment: Idiomatic Rust uses `snake_case` for variables, methods, macros, and fields; `UpperCamelCase` for types and enum variants; and `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE` for statics and constants. Use `TestLoop` instead, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `f()` can change `test_loop` state, then it's natural to add this reference to its signature. This solves the second borrow problem.

```rust
fn run_forever<F>(&mut self, mut f: F)
where
    F: FnMut(&mut Self) -> (), 
{ 
    // call f(self) instead of f()
}

// main
let f = |l: &mut test_loop| {
    l.breakit();
};
```